# Batch file to move profiles remotely from one pc to another on a domain

Tags: command-line, batch

I think it would be simple, just use a set /p line and xcopy to name the pc, user and move the files to where they need to be. But when I write my code

```
@echo off

Set /p OldPC=Please enter the old PC name:
Set /p NewPC=Please enter the new PC name:
Set /p Name=Please enter the users name:

xcopy "\\OldPC\C$\Users\Name\Desktop" "\\NewPC\C$\Users\Name\Desktop" /e
xcopy "\\OldPC\C$\Users\Name\Documents" "\\NewPC\C$\Users\Name\Documents" /e
xcopy "\\OldPC\C$\Users\Name\Music" "\\NewPC\C$\Users\Name\Music" /e
xcopy "\\OldPC\C$\Users\Name\Downloads" "\\NewPC\C$\Users\Name\Downloads" /e
xcopy "\\OldPC\C$\Users\Name\Contacts" "\\NewPC\C$\Users\Name\Contacts" /e
xcopy "\\OldPC\C$\Users\Name\Favorites" "\\NewPC\C$\Users\Name\Favorites" /e
xcopy "\\OldPC\C$\Users\Name\Links" "\\NewPC\C$\Users\Name\Links" /e
xcopy "\\OldPC\C$\Users\Name\Vidoes" "\\NewPC\C$\Users\Name\Videos" /e
xcopy "\\OldPC\C$\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes" "\\NewPC\C$\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\" /e
pause
```

I get multiple errors. Any help here sure would be appreciated.

Comment: In all your examples you need to use `\\%OldPC%\C$` just like that for the variable that is set. Just change `\\OldPC` to be `\\%OldPC%` instead. You will also need to do the same with the `%NewPC%` and `%Name%` as well and you should be all set. Otherwise please post the errors you are getting but it seems you simply are not putting the percent sign around the variable names you set.

Comment: When I run the batch file nothing happens it simply disappears even though I have pause set at the end. I have checked the %NewPC% and nothing shows up.

Comment: Ok that worked perfectly, I found a mis typed word.. You Rock!!!

Comment: Great, I've added as an Answer for you since you confirmed what I suggested helped resolve your issue... See explanation in short here: https://i.imgur.com/hG8jbw0.png  for accepting an answer when you see this just in case since I see you're a new member.

Comment: Roger - Please be sure to check the tick to accept just next to the upper left side of my answer. See the above comment link with a screen shot of this too.

Answer (score 0):

When you [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) a variable in batch, in most cases you will surround the variable name with percent signs (`%`) to ensure the value which is set will be used when the variable is referenced accordingly.

---

### Example Script

You simply just need to reference `%OldPC%`, `%NewPC%`, and `%Name%` in that format in the logic after the [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) commands to ensure the values return accordingly.

```
Set /p OldPC=Please enter the old PC name:
Set /p NewPC=Please enter the new PC name:
Set /p Name=Please enter the users name:  

xcopy "\\%OldPC%\C$\Users\%Name%\Desktop" "\\%NewPC%\C$\Users\%Name%\Desktop" /e
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)